# Finding the number of ordered pairs of a subset

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered pairs (,), where ,  are subsets of {1,2,3,4,5} have:

1.)  ∩  = ∅ ?

2.)  ∩  = {1} ?

3.) | ∩ | = 1 ?

Comment: Any thoughts?  If this is too hard, start with a smaller set, say $\{1,2\}$.  Then do $\{1,2,3\}$

Answer (score 1):

if $A \cap B = \emptyset $

Then for each of the 5 elements there are 3 possibilities, it can belong to A, belong to B or belong to neither.

So $$N_1=3^5$$

similarly

$$N_2 = 3^4 \\ N_3 = 5\times 3^4$$

Answer (score 1):

Each element in the set {$1,2,3,4,5$} pretty much has $4$ options

- Be placed into $A$ *and* $B$
- Be place into $A$
- Be placed into $B$
- Not be placed into $A$ or $B$

1.) In this case each element is only going to have $3$ options since we can't place an element into both $A$ *and* $B$. So we have $3^5=243$ possibilities.

2.) In this case we only have a single option for what we can do with the $1$ in our set, since it must be placed into both $A$ *and* $B$. And for the rest of our elements we cannot place them into both $A$ *and* $B$. So we have $3^4=81$ possibilities.

3.) In this case we have $5$ ways to pick an element that we are going to place into place into both $A$ *and* $B$. 
And for the rest of our elements we cannot place them into both $A$ *and* $B$. So we have $5*3^4=405$ possibilities.